# How to use regex to count polysyllables in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to count the polysyllables from a text file. I have managed to count the syllables and few others(i.e., no. of words, sentence and etc.) but unable to get the count of polysyllables. Searched on internet and found very few information on polysyllables to work with. Appreciate if anyone could help.

```
static void syllableCount(String text) {

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aeiouy]+[^$e(,.:;!?)]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
int syllables = 0;
while (m.find()){
syllables++; 
}        
System.out.println("Syllables: " + syllables);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
//accept file name or directory name through command line args 
//String fname =args[0]; 

//pass the filename or directory name to File object 
File f = new File("in3.txt"); 

try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f)) {
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            
String text = scanner.nextLine();
int words = text.split(" |\n|\t").length;
int sentences = text.split("\\.|\\?|!").length;
int characters = text.replaceAll(" |\n|\t","").split("").length;

syllableCount(text);

**//polySyllables(text);**
```

Comment: I question whether regex alone is adequate for what you are trying to do here.  In general, I think you would need some kind of linguistic parser.

Comment: To add to what Tim said, you can read this: [What is meant by “Now you have two problems”?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

Comment: Does your assignment give a definition for "syllable" that's different from the usual meaning if the word? Counting the actual number of syllables in a word in English is a hard problem.

Comment: The definition goes like this; To count the number of syllables you should use letters a, e, i, o, u, y as vowels. You can see here examples and intricacies with determining vowels in a word with 100% accuracy. So, let's use the following 4 rules:

1. Count the number of vowels in the word.
2. Do not count double-vowels (for example, "rain" has 2 vowels but only 1 syllable).
3. If the last letter in the word is 'e' do not count it as a vowel (for example, "side" has 1 syllable).
4. If at the end it turns out that the word contains 0 vowels, then consider this word as a 1-syllable one.